# Unable to use string.contains() in kotlin `when` expression

Tags: android, kotlin

I am new to `kotlin`, I have tried several ways to use following code

```
val strAction = "Grid"
 when(strAction){
   strAction.contains("Grid")->println("position is 1")
 }
```

In above code **strAction.contains("Grid")** this line is showing me an error that Incompatible Type

[image]

Comment: I dont understand why there is downvote

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Try this remove **`when(strAction)`** parameter from `when`

```
val strAction = "Grid"    

when {
  strAction.contains("Grid") -> println("position is 1")
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your help but it didn't worked for me still facing same issue

Comment: @YoLo remove **`strAction`** from `when` no need to pass that

Answer (score 86):

You can also combine `when` and `with` to get a nice syntax:

```
with(strAction) {
  when {
    contains("Grid") -> println("position is 1")
    contains("bar") -> println("foo")
    startsWith("foo") -> println("bar")
    else -> println("foobar")
  }
}
```

You can also save the result of `when` into a property:

```
val result = with(strAction) {
  when {
    contains("bar") -> "foo"
    startsWith("foo") -> "bar"
    else -> "foobar"
  }
}

println(result)
```

Comment: Thanks that's the best reply imo, there is a way to "factorise" the "contains" so i don't need to type it every line if I only want contains directive ?

Comment: It's a good answer but Alexey's answer below also explains _why_ the original code failed. Very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47450103/131929

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to pass `strAction`

```
val strAction = "Grid"

 when {
   strAction.contains("Grid") -> println("position is 1")
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If there's only one case in your `when`, I'd recommend to use `if` instead. That's already what you're trying to do there:

```
val strAction = "Grid"
if (strAction.contains("Grid")) {
   println("position is 1")
}
```

Even shorter, isn't it?

Just for the record: You switch on a `String` (in `when`) but have `Boolean` cases, which won't work. What would do the trick, though:

```
val strAction = "Grid"
when (strAction.contains("Grid")) {
   true->println("position is 1")
}
```

But again, do `if`.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers explain how to fix the problem but not what the problem actually is. Your code calculates `strAction.contains("Grid")` (which will be a `Boolean`) and then *compares `strAction` with this value*. I.e. it's equivalent to

```
if (strAction == strAction.contains("Grid")) {
   println("position is 1")
}
```

They can't be equal because the types are incompatible, so this branch could never be taken and the compiler tells you this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Kotlin **in**

```
if ("Grid" in strAction) { println("position is 1") }
```